# Which parameters to pass into Angular JS custom directive controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to create a custom directive which needs to use a separate controller because it needs to have functions which can be called by child directives.

Here is my code so far:

```
angular.module('myDirectives').controller('SlideInMenuController', function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {

    $scope.isOpen = false;

    // Toggle Function
    this.toggle = function(){

        $scope.$apply(function(){
            $scope.isOpen = !$scope.isOpen;
        });

    };


    // Watch $scope.isOpen and open the menu
    $scope.$watch('isOpen', function() {

        if($scope.isOpen == true){
            $element.attr('is-open', true);
        }
        else{
            $element.attr('is-open', false);
        }

        return false;

    });

}

angular.module('myDirectives').directive('slideInMenu', function ($swipe) {

    return {

        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: {},
        controller:'SlideInMenuController'        

    };

});


angular.module('myDirectives').directive('slideInMenuToggle', function ($swipe) {

    return {

        restrict: 'EA',
        require: '^slideInMenu',

        link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs, SlideInMenuCtrl) {

            $element.bind('click', function(){
                SlideInMenuCtrl.toggle();
            });

        }        

    };

});
```

(Note: I'm using ng-annotate so I don't have to write all my dependencies twice)

I need to inject the $swipe service into the directive controller but a normal controller would't have $scope, $element, $attrs as the first three parameters. This has made me wonder if I should be putting those into the link function instead and doing DOM stuff there, but if I do that what goes in the controller and what goes in to the link function.

I've read numerous blogs and SO answers that say what order compile/link/controller are run in but still can't find a clear answer as to whatin my above example should go where.

Any help would really be appreciated.

Comment: "I need to inject the $swipe service": go ahead, its perfectly reasonable. "but a normal controller would't have...": yours is a controller intended to be used by directives; again perfectly reasonable to depend on directive-specific stuff. (BTW `$attrs` is not used by the code above, you can remove it.) Your implementation seems very OK to me - save for one thing: I would rather call `$apply` from `element.bind`, which is called externally to Angular rather than from `SlideInMenuController.toggle`. Or am I missing a point?

Comment: So, normally dependencies can be injected in any order. I thought $scope,  $element and $attrs had to be in the correct order because they were normal function parameters rather than dependencies being injected. If they're just like any other dependency then they can go in any order like ($swipe, $element, $scope)? If so, then how come some people get away with calling them (scope, element, attrs) without the dollar sign?

Comment: As for the $scope.$apply, I don't totally understand why I put it where I put t. I just know I had to put it there to get it to work ;-)I could try moving it to the bind in the toggle directive if you think that makes more sense.

Comment: HI, see the valid points in Werlang's answer and also: 1) Yes, the *link* function needs the arguments in the specific order. The controller is dependency injected in the order you ask. And the names do not matter you can do `['$http', function($q) {...}]` and `$q` will be the `$http` service (a nice option if  if you like pain, like `#define TRUE FALSE` in C :)

Comment: 2) For the `$apply`: yes, to me it makes more sense: `bind` is called from outside of Angular (directly from the browser). It has to notify Angular for the dirty checking to work. The method of the controller may, in principle, get called from inside Angular. In this case you will get `digest already in progress` errors.

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos, Is there any chance you could show me how to use apply with elelemt.bind? I've tried wrapping the SlideInMenuCtrl.toggle(); in a $scope.$apply(function(){...}) which is inside the element.bind but it doesn't seem to be triggering the digest cycle. Does the $scope.$apply wrap the call to element.bind?

Comment: It should be: `$element.bind('click', function() {  $scope.$apply(function() {  SlideInMenuCtrl.toggle();  });  });`, i.e. "*bind* wraps *$apply* wraps the actual code".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two kind of functions for AngularJS. Neither of which is intended to be called directly.

1) **Injectables**: functions that receive parameters, whose names must (with a few exceptions) be registered with **dependency injection** subsystem. *It's the reason for ng-annotate to exist*. You can also use array notation for these.

```
angular.module('stackOverflow').service('answer', ['myService', function(myService) {
...
}]);
```

Some examples are the ones you pass to `angular.module()` functions, like `service()`, `factory()`, `directive()`, `controller()`.

2) **Plain functions**. These have no special handling, it's vanilla JavaScript. They are passed to link and compile slots in directive definition objects.

You can omit rightmost parameters if you have no use for them, but not others. As the order of parameters is fixed, you cannot reorder them. But **you can call them whatever you want**.

That's it about functions.

About *conventions using $*: beware! AngularJS builtin services are prefixed with $, so you should name parameters this way for injectable functions. For all other cases, don't prefix with $: your own functions and positional parameters like you see in link() and compile(). **Prefix with $ in those functions is misleading and bad guidance**.

To better distinguish parameters for compile() and link, you can prefix with `t` for template and `i` for instance. Nowadays I prefer to use those unprefixed. It's better for moving them around.

```
compile: function (tElement, tAttrs) {
    return function link(scope, iElement, iAttrs, ctrls) {
    };
}
```